# Is it possible to import a form straight from a drupal website into my access database?

Tags: database, drupal, ms-access-2010

This might be a very stupid question but I'll try it anyway. We currently have our company website [TeamDeals Energie Collectief](http://www.teamdeals.nl) running on Drupal and next to that we have an access database with all our customer info. We would like to automatically import submitted forms from the website into our database. The problem is we have no idea if and how this could be accomplished.

Comment: This is possible but it depends exactly what technology you have available and it also depends on your hosting setup. I would look at this module https://drupal.org/project/views_data_export

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a view exporting your form results in CSV (you can configure your view so it fetches only last days submissions or something like that) with drupal.org/project/views_data_export, set a URL to this view, and have a daily cron job on your remote system (hosting your access database) like "wget http://www.teamdeals.nl/path_to_your_csv_view". Maybe not very clean but it works (I saw this once).

You might have problems trying to get form submissions from a view. Assuming you're using webforms, have a look to [this post](https://drupal.org/node/1658784).

You can (should ?) restrain your CSV view URL access to a IP array (on your view : Page settings -> Access permission -> PHP code :

```
return in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('your.remote.server.ip'));
```

).

I repeat, there is certainly a better / more secure solution, but it might be a starting point.